# html5 datepicker jquery min max and format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I wrote a simple function to set min/max dates for datepicker and format selected date.
But when I set the range the format returns to default mm/dd/yy
Please note that the page in HTML5.
and here the code

```
$(function () {
    var pickerFormat = {
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    };
    var range = {
        minDate: "-2y",
        maxDate: new Date()
    };

    $("#datepicker1").datepicker(range, pickerFormat);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same object for both date format and picker range.

***for example***

```
$(function () {
     var pickerFormatrange = {
          dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy",
          minDate: "-2y",
          maxDate: new Date()
     }; 
     $("#datepicker1").datepicker(pickerFormatrange);
 });
```